# rosdep does not want to install pip packages

Tags: ros, python, rosdep, pip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I have a package with a `<run_depend>` on a python pip package, e.g. python-fysom - which is defined [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml) - rosdep does not want to install it:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths . -v
...
resolve_all: resource [my_package] requires rosdep keys [rospy, message_generation, std_msgs, catkin, python-fysom, rospy, std_msgs, message_runtime]
loading view [*default*] with rospkg loader
resolution: pip [fysom]
uninstalled: []
All system dependencies have been satisified
```

fysom is not installed:

```
$ pip uninstall fysom
Cannot uninstall requirement fysom, not installed
```

Am I doing it wrong or is that a bug in rosdep?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207157/rosdep-does-not-want-to-install-pip-packages/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths . --simulate -v
> ```

Is the `--simulate` just there for testing, or are you actually trying to install things using that line? From the `rosdep install` help:

```
 -s, --simulate        Simulate install
```

So it won't actually install anything, but only print out what it *would* do without `--simulate`.

Remove that option and try again.

---

Edit:

> Sorry for the confusion, the error is the same without `--simulate`, I removed it from the question.

I cannot reproduce this on a Precise/Hydro installation with a skeleton pkg that contained just a manifest with a `<run_depend>python-fysom</run_depend>` in it. Running `rosdep install ..` on the workspace resulted in `pip` being invoked, and `python-fysom` being installed.

Can you try to reinitialise the `rosdep` cache using `rosdep update` and then try again?

In all cases: please update your question with information on your Linux and ROS distribution (name, version), as well as perhaps the pkg that you are running `rosdep` against. The [OS name identifiers and supported package managers](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/rosdep_yaml_format.html#os-name-identifiers-and-supported-package-managers) section of the [rosdep YAML format](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/rosdep_yaml_format.html) page seems to suggest `pip` is only available on Ubuntu (and probably derivatives).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2015-04-16**:
Sorry for the confusion, the error is the same without `--simulate`, I removed it from the question.